# получить изображение по http запросу

Tags: php, http

есть картинка, которая доступна по http запросу

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nD5tkMTF7z9QHIR8GfDc6BBjPZlH6sAuCvS_nOWsyxi0oPc9OLGq7DRnlOHz-1cRZETPRA=s220

как возможно получить картинку выполнив этот запрос в php?

Comment: Это видео, а не картинка.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nD5tkMTF7z9QHIR8GfDc6BBjPZlH6sAuCvS_nOWsyxi0oPc9OLGq7DRnlOHz-1cRZETPRA=s220

Comment: не тот линк скопировал

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php и http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: в каком виде она вам нужна? для чего? может просто echo '<img src="...">';

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я делал для mp3. Аналогично можно сделать для картинок

```
private function saveCallRecord($fileLinks) {
    $newCallRecordContents = '';
    foreach ($fileLinks as $fileLink) {
        $file = 'http:' . $fileLink . '&download=true';
        $newCallRecordContents .= file_get_contents($file);
    }
    $file_name = $this->generateString() . '.mp3';
    return ['file_name' => $file_name, 'result' => file_put_contents('./media/calls/' . $file_name, $newCallRecordContents)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `copy(url_img, path_save)` в помощь.